# What kind of damage could a compromised Mesos task do to a Mesos cluster?

Tags: security, mesos

What kind of worst-case damage could a compromised Mesos Task (launched via the Docker Containerizer) do to the rest of a Mesos cluster?

Answer (score 3):

A task is the unit of work in Mesos: it runs in an Executor (the worker part of a framework, with the scheduler being the other component) on a Mesos Agent and every task is in fact [containerized](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/containerizer/). Since you launch via the Docker containerizer, the damage (to the Mesos Agent the task is running on as well as to the entire cluster) is primarily determined by the runtime mode, so if you don't have a privileged container it's only the sandbox the task can corrupt, otherwise the same damage can be caused that a random process with root privileges can cause (which is not specific to Mesos).

Comment: What would something like while (1) { fork() } do?

Comment: Nothing bad. I tried it out, result see here: https://medium.com/@mhausenblas/fork-bombing-mesos-3830caa520c7